# popup on cell edit - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I need help on pop up msg anytime a cell is edited in column F,H and L

basically i want my team to only add whatsapp numbers.
so msg should convey and ask them to follow that.

like "add whatapp number only"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this simple trigger function:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const column = e.range.getColumn(); 
  // Check if the edit is in column F (6), H (8), or L (12)
  if ([6, 8, 12].includes(column)) {
    // Show a message box with the instruction
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please add WhatsApp numbers only.");
  }
}
```